# Rails - Automatic create admin if there are no admin and login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, bcrypt

I have a sign in of Admins, but when the databases are empty you can't enter because there are no admins user, so i'm trying to create an admin user in the controller, but is not very secure for obious reasons, like this

sessions_admins/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: session_admins_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :email, "Email" %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email", required: true, pattern: '^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$' %>

  <%= f.label :password, "Password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password", required: true %>  

  <%= f.submit "Log In", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

sessions_admins_controller.rb

```
def new
 if signed_in_admin?
  redirect_to admin_dashboard_path
 else
  if Admin.all.count == 0
   Admin.create(name: "Example", email: "admin@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end
 end
end

def create
 admin = Admin.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
 if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  sign_in_admin admin
  ...
 end
end
```

This solution is not "elegant", also insecure, my principal idea was give an encrypted password (and i know the real password) and force save, like this

```
a = Admin.new
a.name = "Example" 
a.email: "admin@example.com" 
a.password_digest: "da39a3ee5e6b4..." #encrypted "foobar"
a.save(:validate => false)
```

But when i try to authenticate

```
Admin.find_by_email("admin@example.com").authenticate("foobar")
```

It gives me this error:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create the initial admin user on the backend?